# web link (internet) navigation error in application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to navigate to a web link when I press a button.
I think it's the same idea as navigating to a XAML page, but instead I put a web page.

Simple page navigation:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I wrote

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.youtube.com", UriKind.Absolute));
```

But when I debug, the app crashes

I am using c#.  (Visual Studio 2012 Express for windows phone 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that:

> I think it's the same idea as navigating to a XAML page, but instead I
>   put a web page.

But you cant use *NavigationService* to navigate to the web page.

I have used this way in one of my projects:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="YouTube" NavigateUri="http://youtube.com" TargetName="_blank" />
```

The key is `TargetName` property. It must be set to `_blank`. This behaves similar to *WebBrowserTask*.

Of course you can make it work like this also:

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com", UriKind.Absolute); 
webBrowserTask.Show();
```